# Why is robocopy slower than Copy-Item over a network share?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

This command takes 1.6 minutes:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse $buildSource $stageShare
```

and this takes 2.1 minutes:

```
robocopy.exe $buildSource $stageShare
```

```bsh
$buildSource = 'C:\MyStuff'
$stageShate = '\\somemachine\someshare\mydir'
```

Do I need switches to make this faster?

Comment: How are you measuring that time? How many time have you performed that test on each action. There could be a number of reasons outside what you provide here that would affect the outcome. How much data is being moved? If robocopy is wasting time displaying details to the screen that would be something to change with logging switches.

Answer (score 3):

I think the time loss you are seeing is time spent outputting data to the console e.g. file progress information. This takes time and you should suppress it to see its affect on your times.

Adapted from [Microsoft Docs for robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy):

> - /NFL    Specifies that file names are not to be logged.
> - /NDL    Specifies that directory names are not to be logged.
> - /NJH    Specifies that there is no job header.
> - /NJS    Specifies that there is no job summary.
> - /NP     Specifies that the progress of the copying operation (the number of files or directories copied so far) will not be displayed.

Removing job summary it not really required for performance gains but it is one more thing.

```
robocopy.exe $buildSource $stageShare /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /np
```